# Get each <li> with child <div> and change the <li>'s <a> attribute

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, menu, disable-link

I'm disabling the links in my menu and turning them into accordion type buttons.
some links don't have children though (dropdowns if you will), and I'd like those to stay as links.

I want to target each LI with a child Div and change that Li's a=href value
I've done that, but i specifically don't want to change any Li's a=href value IF it doesnt have a child Div in the first place.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
        $(function() {
            if ($(window).width() <= 900 & $( 'div.menu-main-menu-container > ul.main-menu > li.menu-item > a' ).attr( 'href' ) != "#") {
                $( 'div.menu-main-menu-container > ul.main-menu > li.menu-item > a' ).each(function() {
                    var old = $(this).attr( 'href' );
                    $(this).attr( 'data-href', old);
                    $(this).attr( 'href', '#');
                });
            } if ($(window).width() > 900 & $( 'div.menu-main-menu-container >     ul.main-menu > li.menu-item > a' ).attr( 'href' ) == "#") {
                $( 'div.menu-main-menu-container > ul.main-menu > li.menu-item >     a' ).each(function() {
                    var old = $(this).attr( 'data-href' );
                    $(this).attr( 'href', old);
                });
            }
        });
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select only the li's with child divs with the jQuery `has` method, for example like this:

```
$('div.menu-main-menu-container > ul.main-menu > li.menu-item').has('div').children('a').....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if ($('li').children().length > 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
if ($('li').children().length == 0)
{
    //do something else
}
```

Also, it seems that you aren't looping through the li's (otherwise I would've suggested using $(this)). There's definitely a better way to accomplish selecting these elements. You have such long strings for the selectors (i.e. 'div.menu-main-menu-container >     ul.main-menu > li.menu-item > a' ) where you can probably reduce to a simple unique class or id.

Comment: Hrmmm..

I should have been clearer, the Li's already have a child <a>
so maybe change the length to 2 or > 1?

but I'm still stuck - how do i then select only the Li's with child div's and edit those Li's <a>'s?
what do i / how do i select in the " //do something "

Comment: Oh that's right! I apologize. Change .children() to .children('div'). Look at the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

you can choose that `li` which first element is `div` like this:

```
$('li > div:first').each(function(){
  $(this).parent('li')
  ......
});
```

hope this can help you :)